# Does anybody know how I can adjust this CSS to achieve the desired hyperlink effect I'd like?

Tags: css

Currently, I just have this in my CSS:

```
a:link
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: underline;
outline: none;
}

a:hover
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve **THIS** type of css effect for my website's hyperlinks?  Basically, the hyperlinks have a background in olive-green-yellow, and when hovering, they turn bright yellow.

[image]

I've looked through w3schools and have googled, firebugged it, viewed the source, but I just can't seem to replicate this type of effect; I just don't know the proper css I'd use.  I'm not trying to copy this website's css; I'd just like to know how they achieved it so I can do something similar to mine.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, you got some answers :)

Comment: BTW, the background-color effect isn't really an "effect" as much as it is a style type. The reason I say this is because most things we call "effects" are things like CSS3 transitions that don't have full cross-browser support. The background-color property DOES have full cross-browser support so there are no worries. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks OakNinja and Raphael!  I didn't expect this wonderful of a response!  I wish I knew it was this easy!  hehe .. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Hopefully, one day I will have a jQuery for you!  That's what is great about SO.  It is so difficult to get started with a new language due to the inability to move forward after you hit the wall, but after you figure out the first few problems, things get easier and easier!

Comment: Absolutely, Raphael.  I'd love to incorporate like ... an effect when you hover over the hyperlink, it "eases" into the bright yellow at a rate (in milliseconds) I choose.  

I learned asp.net basically completely off this website.  Now I've learned WordPress, and things just keep rolling from there.  Thanks again for your time!

Comment: One last thing, keep in mind there is a big trend these days towards accessibility.  What that means is that not everyone viewing your site will be doing it the way you think they will. For example, some will be viewing on their mobile phones, where there is no :hover state. Some are blind and will be viewing on screen readers.  Do some google searches for "responsive design" and "html5 accessibility" to hopefully get you started in the right direction.  The reason I say this is because created slow effects for hovering over links is definitely not recommended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this JFiddle for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/LBsJL/  Dos this help?

```
P
{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
a:link
{
background-color: #aeb05d;
text-decoration: underline;
outline: none;
}

a:hover
{
background-color: yellow;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: BTW, the background-color effect isn't really an "effect" as much as it is a style type.  The reason I say this is because most things we call "effects" are things like CSS3 transitions that don't have full cross-browser support.  The background-color property DOES have full cross-browser support so there are no worries. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, Raphael -- I really do appreciate you taking the time to respond!  And +1 for the fiddle -- so I can play around with it and see what other effects I can manage.  I definitely appreciate your time in helping me out and making that fiddle!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the property `background-color` or am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi MildlyInteresting ... I'm not sure if you were missing anything; I'm not too good with css, so I really didn't know what to add. I experimented with a few things, but just couldn't figure it out.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `background-color: yellow;` on your `a:hover`.
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwUwc/).

Comment: Thanks Adrenaxus!  That seems to be what MildlyInteresting was saying, and was incorporated into the fiddles that you and Raphael provided.  Thank you for taking the time to make that fiddle -- I'll definitely use it!

Comment: Glad I (we) could help. Please accept the answer you consider the most helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a:link
{
color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: underline;
outline: none;
}

a:hover
{
color: #000;
background-color: #1d60ff;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

that's it

Comment: Yep, got it Milche -- thank you for taking hte time to respond!  I just didn't know how to incorporate that background color, and if it would work on all browsers, including some dinosaur browsers.  Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't background-color work?

```
a:link 
{
 color: #1d60ff;
 background-color: #FF0000;
 text-decoration: underline;
 outline: none;
}

a:hover
{
 color: #1d60ff;
 background-color: #00FF00;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, OakNinja ... I just didn't know how to incorporate it, or wasn't doing so properly to work on all browsers.  But Raphael cleared that issue up.  thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Great :) Basic things are basic when you know how to do them :)